# Pass data to the parentViewController [iOS]

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, parent-child, segue

I have this storyboard:
[image]

When I press the "Insegnante" button in the first view controller (wich is called **newCourseViewController**) it show me a table view with a list of teacher. When I press on a teacher (and the method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` is called) I want that the `UITableViewController` "pass" the object pressed to the first view controller.

This is my code for the first view controller **newCourseViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Teacher.h"

@interface newCourseViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic , strong) Teacher *teacher;

@end
```

And this is my code for the first view controller **newCourseViewController.m** (only important code)

```
#import "newCourseViewController.h"
#import "Courses.h"
#import "Teacher.h"
#import "addTeacherToCourseViewController.h"

@interface newCourseViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation newCourseViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setTeacher:(Teacher *)teacher
{
    self.teacher = teacher;
    NSLog(@"Maestro settato!");
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addTeacherToCourse"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setPreviousViewController:self];
    }
}
```

Now the code for the second view controller **addTeacherToCourseViewController-h**

```
@interface addTeacherToCourseViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic , weak) id previousViewController;

@end
```

and the **addTeacherToCourseViewController.m** (only the important method)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Teacher *teacher = [self.teachers getTeacherInPosition:indexPath.row];
    [self.previousViewController setTeacher:teacher];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

In the first view controller in the `prepareForSegue` method I set myself to the `previousViewController` in the second view. Then I "pass" the teacher selected and than I dismiss the second view controller.
When the application execute the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` Xcode crash and the simulator crash.
I can't figure out what is the problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have anything in particular in viewWillAppear on new course controller ?

Comment: No, nothing, but I have solved the problem with delegation. There was an answer to my question below (and I was going to vote as a correct answer), but the user has deleted (do not know why since it was the correct answer). If you resurface the demand will select as the correct one, otherwise I'll write the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send values to parent controller you have to use protocols. I will provide proper steps you should take in order to have your desired functionality working.

1.
Create a protocol for your AddTeacherToCourseController.
In your AddTeacherToCourseController.h add the following right below the imports:

```
@protocol AddTeacherToCourseControllerProtocol <NSObject>
    - (void)yourDelegateMethod:(Teacher *)insegnante;
@end
```

And below interface tag add:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <AddTeacherToCourseControllerProtocol> delegate;
```

2.
In AddTeacherToCourseController.m:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // I would use the existing array you are using to display the teachers in order to select the correct one you want to send back like this:
    // Teacher *teacher = [self.teachers getTeacherInPosition:indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate yourDelegateMethod:[yourTeacherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

[this method will call your delegate method through the protocol and will pass your selected professor to the parent controller]

3.
In your parent controller, your newCourseViewController.h right after interface line add:

```
<AddTeacherToCourseControllerProtocol>
```

4.
If you do not have an Insegnante button action, create one in interface builder [dragging and naming]. Then add the following to this action:

```
// assuming your storyboard is named MainStoryboard. here you create your segue programmatically:
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
addTeacherToCourseViewController *addTeacherController = (addTeacherToCourseViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addTeacherToCourseViewController"];
addTeacherController.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addTeacherController animated:YES];
```

5.
In Interface Builder:

- Remove your segue from Insegnante button.
- Edit the Storyboard Id of 'addTeacherToCourseViewController' to 'addTeacherToCourseViewController'

6.
In newCourseViewController.h write your delegate method:

```
- (void)yourDelegateMethod:(Teacher *)insegnante{
    // Do whatever you want with your Insegnante
    // and be sure to pop the second controller from the view stack:
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Let me know if you have questions and if my answer helped anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give you an exact answer please tell me what object you are using to display your list of professors in your second controller, the tableViewController. I am guessing that is an array of Teacher instances. Is that correct? [class Teacher]